# Scanf for digits

Tags: c, scanf

I am pretty new in C and I have a question about scanf just for digits. What I need to do is scanf in input just 3 digits, antoher characters or symbols should be evaluate as trash. Or maybe I need use `isdigit()` but I am not sure how it works. I have just that, but I know that it doesn't work:

```
scanf("%d, %d, %d", &z, &x, &y);
```

Comment: but I need to read three freestanding digits, for example if I input somthing like: 3nkt 6 u 4, there needs to be taken just digits 3,6,4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could read a string, use a scan set to filter it and convert it to an integer.

See scanf: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/sscanf/

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    char num1[256], num2[256], num3[256]; 

    scanf("%s %s %s", num1, num2, num3);
    sscanf(num1, num2, num3, "%[0-9]d %[0-9]d %[0-9]d", num1, num2, num3);

    int n1 = atoi(num1), n2 = atoi(num2), n3 = atoi(num3); // convert the strings to int

    printf("\n%d %d %d\n", n1, n2, n3);

    return 0;
}
```

Sample Input & Output:

```
2332jbjjjh 7ssd 100

2332 7 100
```

Comment: nice solution, but its not generic. I give vote up, because of using of sscanf function

Answer (score 0):

A little more complicated solution, but prevents overflow of array and works for any kind of input. get_numbers_from_input function takes array where read numbers will be put and maximum count of numbers in array and returns count of numbers read from standard input. function reads characters from standard input until enter is pressed.

```
#include <stdio.h>    
//return number readed from standard input
//numbers are populated into numbers array
int get_numbers_from_input(int numbers[], int maxNumbers) {
    int count = -1;
    char c = 0;
    char digitFound = 0;
    while ((c = getc(stdin)) != '\n') {
        if (c >= '0' && c <= '9') {
            if (!digitFound) {
                if (count == maxNumbers) {
                    break; //prevent overflow!
                }
                numbers[++count] = (c - '0');
                digitFound = 1;
            }
            else {
                numbers[count] = numbers[count] * 10 + (c - '0');
            }
        }
        else if (digitFound) {
            digitFound = 0;
        }
    }

    return count + 1; //because count starts from -1
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int numbers[100]; //max 100 numbers! 

    int numbersCount = get_numbers_from_input(numbers, 100);
    //output all numbers from input
    for (int c = 0; c < numbersCount; ++c) {
        printf("%d ", numbers[c]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this.

If the first char is not a digit.
Use "%*[^0-9]" to skip chars which is not digits.

' * ' is an optional starting asterisk indicates that the data is to be read from the stream but ignored (i.e. it is not stored in the location pointed by an argument), and ' ^ ' means any number of characters none of them specified as characters between the brackets.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int x,y,z;
    if(!scanf("%d",&x)==1) scanf("%*[^0-9] %d",&x);
    if(!scanf("%d",&y)==1) scanf("%*[^0-9] %d",&y);
    if(!scanf("%d",&z)==1) scanf("%*[^0-9] %d",&z);
    printf("%d %d %d\n",x,y,z);
   return 0;
}
```

Input & Output

```
fehwih 2738     @$!(#)12[3]
2738 12 3
```

Reference from: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged. Please add an explanation (and be sure to differentiate your answer from those that were posted years ago)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.