# Switch case 0: entering 0 and entering a letter

Tags: c, switch-statement

```
int DisplaySchedule()
{
    int nDisplaySchedule_Choice;

    system("cls");
    printf("----- DISPLAY SCHEDULE -----\n");
    printf("Pick departure station\n\t");
    printf("[1] San Pedro\n\t");
    printf("[2] Santa Rosa\n\t");
    printf("[3] Calamba\n\n\t");
    printf("[9] Go Back\n\t");
    printf("[0] Exit\n\n");
    printf("Choice: ");
    scanf("%d", &nDisplaySchedule_Choice);
    printf("\n");

    switch (nDisplaySchedule_Choice) {
        case 1: SanPedro(); break;
        case 2: SantaRosa(); break;
        case 3: Calamba(); break;
        case 9: OpeningScreen(); break;
        case 0: printf("Summary()"); break;
        default:
            printf("ERROR. INPUT A VALID RESPONSE.\n\n");
            DisplaySchedule();
            break;
    }
    return;
}
```

I have this code in which when I enter a letter, instead of printing the error message, it prints `case 0:` instead. Is there any way for me to make it so that `case 0:` will only function if and only if I enter "0" in the `scanf` statement?

Comment: Always check a returned value of `scanf`.

Comment: You could set `nDisplaySchedule_Choice` to a 'wrong' value (say, -1) before the `scanf` call - it would then remain at this value if invalid input is given.

Comment: You might also initialize `nDisplaySchedule_Choice` to an invalid value (like `-1`).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scanf for digits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13324793/scanf-for-digits)

Comment: @anatolyg Yeah it's a duplicate but the answers there were pretty low quality. I'd expect a good answer to either deal with result of `scanf` or show a `fgets` alternative.

Answer (score 2):

If `scanf` fails to read a value (for instance because you told it to read an `int` and gave it a letter) it won't change your variable. So `nDisplaySchedule_Choice` won't change in a way that you can check in your `switch`. At least not if you don't initialize it - you can however set it to a value that is not covered by your `switch`, and if it didn't change, you know that `scanf` failed to read a value.

Or you could check the [return value of `scanf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/) to see if it managed to read a value:

```
int result = scanf("%d", &nDisplaySchedule_Choice);
if (result == 0) {
    int c;
    while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF); // flush the invalid input
    printf("ERROR. INPUT A VALID RESPONSE.\n\n");
    DisplaySchedule();
}
else switch ...
```

Answer (score 2):

You have [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) here.

`scanf`, when scanning for int (`%d`), fails because you input a character - due to *matching failure*. Thus not reading anything into `nDisplaySchedule_Choice` at all.

Since `nDisplaySchedule_Choice` is uninitialized to start with, it just happens to have `0` and thus goes to `case 0`.

The solution is to check the `scanf` return value before proceeding to use `nDisplaySchedule_Choice`. `scanf` returns the number of items successfully scanned.